# Using Entity Framework, return all rows with date port of DateTime column equal to today

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework to work with a MySql database.  I have a DateTime column that I want to query and return all rows where the date portion of the DateTime column's values are within the range of the current day.

Comment: Are you intending to use LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming the DateTime property is not normalized to day, so that it may have any value throughout the day.

The most straightforward way staying in Entity Framework land is probably something like:

```
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;                    // earliest time today 
            DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);      // earliest time tomorrow

            var q = db.Objects
                        .Where(x => x.Time >= today)
                        .Where(x => x.Time < tomorrow);
```

This is a general technique that can find any range of times (not just specific days).

If the table has or will have many rows, you'll want to check that it is indexed to prevent having to scan the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ to Entities:

```
private readonly Entities _db = new Entities();

var entities = (from t in _db.table
                    where t.dateColumn.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today)
                    select t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
SELECT ??? FROM YourTable WHERE DATE(dateTime) = DATE(NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he means where the date part of the datetime field is today's date, correct?
In that case something like this would work:

```
SELECT CAST(yourdatecol AS DATE) FROM thetable WHERE CAST(yourdatecol AS date) = CURDATE();
```